# Login page needs to be prompted if user is not authorized to access specific controller or URL in spring security. How to achieve that?

Tags: spring-boot, jsp, spring-security

I'm using spring-boot, spring-security and JSP. If I click on a button it should go to a controller if user is logged in. Otherwise, it should first ask user to login and then get back to that page. In short, user should see the page if he is logged in. How can I achieve this?

I think filters/antmatchers might be used but I am wondering how the user will get back to that particular page/controller after logging in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using something like this to allow users access to certain pages and then set the default success url accordingly.  You can have a home page as I use here represented by "/" and once a user logs in they are redirected to your /welcome page.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // Public access to login, landing, and error pages
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/login", "/errorpage").permitAll();


        // Static resource permissions
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**", "/fonts/**", "/images/**", "/webfonts/**", "/js/**", "/webjars/**", "/messages/**")
                .permitAll();

        // Login specifications
        http.formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/welcome", true);

        // Logout specifications
        http
                .logout()
                .deleteCookies("remove")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .permitAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try that and let you know. Thanks for the answer Paul

Comment: @SandeepAmarnath Any luck?

Comment: I didn't try that yet Paul but I'm sure it works out well.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` implementation, you need to inform a **formLogin** and specify the **loginPage**.
That's just enough to Spring to use the endpoint `/login` this way.

If you try to access a page without logged, for example `/profile`, you will be redirected to `/login`, and after logged, you'll be redirected to `/profile`

And in this example, you have 3 pages accessible without authentication `/ ,`/home`and`/info`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    ...

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home", "/info" ).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

...

}
```

Comment: I think I had missed anyRequest().authenticated() and I guess that fulfills my requirement. Anyways I'll give it a try, thanks